# Meta Query in Wordpress is being ignored

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a custom post type called 'employees' and now trying to query on it by calling this post type after it has shown the department page.  I created a custom meta box with a couple of arguments in it, such as department, with a drop down, so people can easily assign the person to the right department. If the criteria is met, the picture of the employees (or in my case, the word `crap` as test) should show.

However, I seem to have a problem with trying to get the right query. My code is as following. I need to clear out stuff still, and its code in progress, so dont shoot down how it is programmed. Its just the query for now.

This is the code for the meta box

```
$prefix = 'shm_';
$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'meta-employees',
    'title' => 'Overige informatie',
    'page' => 'employees',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'position',
            'desc' => 'The name of the job position',
            'id' => $prefix . 'position',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'department',
            'desc' => 'Select the department this employee is working in',
            'id' => $prefix . 'department',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array('Board', 'Sales, Marketing & Revenue', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5', 'Option 6')
        )
    )
);
```

And this is for the query

```
 <?php
 if(!is_front_page()){
            if (is_page('board')){
                $page = 'board';
            }elseif (is_page('sales-marketing-revenue')){
                $page = 'Sales, Marketing & Revenue';
            }

            echo $page;

            $i = 0;

            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type' => 'employees',
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    'key'     => 'department',
                    'value' => $page,
                    'compare' => '=',
                )
            );  


            query_posts($args);
                if ( have_posts() ) : 
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    echo "crap";
            ?>


                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

this piece technically works, however it spits out all employees instead of the ones I set on a specific department, such as `board`. When I print the array everything seems to work fine.

`Array ( [numberposts] => -1 [post_type] => employees [meta_query] => Array ( [key] => department [value] => Sales, Marketing & Revenue [compare] => = ) )`

Yet the sales marketing & revenue have only 1 person attached to it, not 3 (the total of employees I have entered so far) which are displayed. It looks like it's ignoring the meta query.

Anybody can help me on this?

Comment: In the codex of Wordpress to be exact: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went looking in the database on how it was entered. I realized I updated the file a while ago with the correct lettering. Wordpress didn't update the these changes in the database, thus I had to call the old keyname, instead of the new one. I guess this is a flaw on my side, why it couldn't read it. Correct query now is as following.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'employees',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'shm_text',
            'value' => $page,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
```